# How to return a Dictionary<K,V> from a stored procedure with other data

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a result set of data I want to return from a stored Procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE Notifications.Email_GetSubstitutions
    @ReportType varchar(100)
AS
    SELECT et.TemplateID, et.OnlineTemplateID, et.OnlineTemplateID, et.EmailFrom, et.ReportType, els.EmailSubstitutionName, erts.EmailSubstitutionID, erts.EmailSubstitutionResult
    FROM Notifications.Email_Template et
    INNER JOIN Notifications.Email_Reference_TemplateSubstitution erts ON erts.TemplateId = et.TemplateID
    INNER JOIN Notifications.Email_List_Substitution els ON erts.TemplateSubstitutionId = els.EmailSubstitutionID
    WHERE et.ReportType = @ReportType
GO
```

I want the erts.EmailSubstitutionID and erts.EmailSubstitutionResult to be returned as a Dictionary in the (C#) Entity Framework sProc result.

Is there an extension method or something I can do in EF to convert only those two items to a Dictionary or should I do a separate sProc call that returns the results in and convert that?

Comment: Why use EF at all if you're just going to call a stored procedure?  Use something lighter like Dapper in that case.

Comment: Take a look at grouping in LINQ: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx

Comment: @DavidL I don't have a choice right now. My company is currently using EF

Comment: @RavB I didn't think about using groupBy after it was called thanks!